# How to get the int Value of other class's int variable?(XCode5) I'm confused

Tags: ios, xcode5, public, object-code

This is `MyScene.h`:

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
@interface MyScene : SKScene
@property (nonatomic) int monstersDestroyed;
@end
```

This is `MyScene.m`:

```
if( someCondition ){
    self.monsterPassed++;
    NSLog(@"MonsterPassed : %d",self.monsterPassed);
}
```

The console will show "MonsterPassed : 0" ... "MonsterPassed : 1"...etc. nicely.

This is `ViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *DestroyeCountLabel;
@end
```

This is `ViewController.m`:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyScene.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer * backgroundMusicPlayer;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

MyScene *monsterDestroyerValue = [[MyScene alloc]init];

self.DestroyeCountLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Monster Destroyed:%d",monsterDestroyerValue.monstersDestroyed];
...
}
```

The problem is that in `ViewController.m` it won't show in my label, it only show "Monster Destroyed: 0". Why? I already searched but I can't find any solution.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of your scene and trying to retrieve a value from it.

Answer (score 1):

You're only setting the DestroyeCountLabel's text once. Setting the monstersDestroyed variable after this won't automatically update the DestroyeCountLabel. There are countless ways to do this. My suggestion is to go through some of Apple's tutorials to get a better grip on programming before diving in.